# Lagrangian Mechanics - Normal Modes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, normal-modes

[image]

System is as in the diagram shown with the hoop having mass $M$, bead having mass $m$ and the moment of inertia about the pivot point for the hoop is given by $I = 2MR^2 $.

For the bead, we have

$$ x = R \sin (\theta) + R \sin (\phi) \\ y = - R \cos (\theta) - R \cos (\phi). $$

$$ \dot{x} = -R \dot{\theta} \sin (\theta) - R \dot{\phi} \sin (\phi) \\ \dot{y} = R \dot{\theta} \cos (\theta ) + R \dot{\phi} \cos (\phi) $$
We end up with a Lagrangian of the form

$$ \mathcal L = \dfrac{1}{2}m (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 ) + \dfrac{1}{2} I \dot{\theta}^2 + mgR \left(\cos (\theta) + \cos (\phi) \right).$$

$$ \mathcal L = \dfrac{1}{2}m R^2  (\dot{\theta}^2 +\dot{\phi}^2 + 2 \dot{\theta} \dot {\phi} (\sin (\theta) \sin (\phi) + \cos (\theta) \cos (\phi)  ) + \dfrac{1}{2} I \dot{\theta}^2 + mgR \left(\cos (\theta) + \cos (\phi) \right).$$

$$ \mathcal L = \dfrac{1}{2}m R^2 \left (\dot{\theta}^2 +\dot{\phi}^2 + 2 \dot{\theta} \dot {\phi} \cos ( \phi - \theta ) \right) + MR^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + mgR \left(\cos (\theta) + \cos (\phi) \right). $$

Taylor expand using $ \cos (x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} $ and ignore all constant terms in the resulting expansion. For the cross term in theta and phi, we only need to consider the zeroth order expansion. This gives an approximate Lagrangian

$$ \mathcal L \approx \dfrac{1}{2} m R^2 \left( \dot{\theta}^2 +\dot{\phi}^2 + 2 \dot{\theta} \dot {\phi} \right) + MR^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - mgR \left( \dfrac{\theta^2}{2} + \dfrac{\phi^2}{2} \right) $$

Expand to second order and differentiating gives us the linearised Euler Lagrange equations

$$ (m+2M) R^2 \ddot{\theta} + MR^2 \ddot {\phi } = - mgR \theta \\ mR^2 \ddot{\theta} + mR^2 \ddot {\phi} = -mgR \phi $$

In matrix form, we obtain:

$$ R^2 \pmatrix{ m+2M & m \\  \\m & m+ } \pmatrix { \ddot{\theta}\\  \\ \ddot{\phi} } =-mgR \pmatrix{\theta  \\ \\ \phi}$$

Find the inverse matrix and premultiply on both sides...

$$ \pmatrix { \ddot{\theta}\\  \\ \ddot{\phi} } = - \underbrace{ \dfrac{g}{2MR} \pmatrix{ m & -m \\  \\-m & m+2M } }_{ = \Omega} \pmatrix{\theta  \\ \\ \phi}$$

Consider the case of equal masses $m=M$. Then defining the "fundamental frequency" $ \omega_0^2 = \dfrac{g}{R} $, we obtain $$ \Omega = \dfrac{\omega_0^2}{2} \pmatrix { 1 & -1 \\ \\ -1 & 3 } .$$

When calculating the eigenfrequencies of the normal modes, I obtain $$ \omega = \sqrt{1 \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} } \omega_0 $$ which appears to be in disagreement with the given solution of $ \omega = \left( \sqrt 2 \omega_0, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \omega_0 \right) $ and I'm not sure where exactly the mistake is.

Comment: Where is the diagram?

Comment: @ggcg Apologies, must have forgotten to upload it at first but it's up now :)

Comment: I think you may be missing a potential energy term.  And I'm not sure about the sign, where are you defining the origin?  and directions?

Comment: x and y are right and upwards respectively, I omitted all constant terms from the Lagrangian when linearizing.

Comment: your matrix is incorrect because the eigenvalues are right.. so you'll have to show that work

Comment: @InertialObserver I've expanded in more detail about how I obtained the matrix equations

Comment: You state "for the bead we have..." what about the ring?  You are missing a term imo.

Comment: @ggcg Do you mean the hoop? I think we only need to account for the rotational energy, but just as a check I tried defining the hoop's coordinates as $X = R \ sin \theta, Y = -R \cos \theta $ and adding in the appropriate kinetic/potential terms for the hoop and it still doesn't result in the given answers

Comment: It has a center of mass, and mass.  So it has gravitational potential energy too.  It is allowed to move about the pivot, right?

Comment: @ggcg I think so, but even if the hoop moves wouldn't it's CoM remain at the same height?

Comment: Not if it's rotating.  Its CoM would make a circular arc about the pivot.  You need t include the gravitational potential of the hoop.

Comment: @ggcg Just tried it again with an extra $mgR \cos \theta$ potential term in the lagrangian and still doesn't give the correct result

Comment: Then there are other issues.